# if error occurred in doAfterSuccess Observer onError not call

Tags: android, rx-java2

When I use retrofit with Single if error throw from doAfterSuccess observer onError not call and app crash(UndeliverableException) but when I create Single myself and throw an exception from a doAfterSuccess observer onError call.

Why doAfterSuccess behave two different way?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Single` protocol is defined as follows: `onSubscribe (onSuccess | onError)?`. In words, if `onSuccess` is called, `onError` can't be called and vice versa. The `doAfterSuccess` can nowhere to go with respect to this protocol and to avoid losing possibly important exceptions, it is routed to the global error handler. The [wiki](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#error-handling) has more detailed explanations about it.

If you find yourself wanting to invoke `onError` after an `onSuccess`, you are probably using the wrong type. The `Observable` protocol allows calling `onError` from whitin or after an `onNext`.

Alternatively, use `try-catch` in your unreliable `onSuccess` handler and call the same code as you'd call from `onError`.

```
Single.just(1)
.doAfterSuccess(v -> {
    try {
       process(v);
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
       reportError(ex);
    }
})
.subscribe(v -> { /* ok */ }, e -> { reportError(e); });
```